# How to retrieve series of images from mysql and display them in JSP

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to build an array by fetching data from mysql. The array include text and pictures. So far everything went good but now I have no idea how to display these picture from the memolist on the JSP page. All I can see are just bunch of bytes. Let's see:

My DBQueries looks like this:

```
public static ArrayList<Memo> selectAllMemoList()
{
    DBConnectionPool pool = DBConnectionPool.getInstance();
    Connection connection = pool.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    String query = "SELECT Users.picture, Users.username, Messages.subject, Messages.date, Messages.msg_id " +
            "FROM Messages, Users " +
            "WHERE Messages.uid_fk = Users.uid " +
            "ORDER BY date DESC";
    try
    {
      ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
      rs = ps.executeQuery();

      ArrayList<Memo> memolist = new ArrayList<Memo>(); 

      String dbSqlTimestamp = "";

      while (rs.next()) {
         m.setUserpicture(rs.getString("picture"));
         m.setUsername(rs.getString("username"));
         m.setSubject(rs.getString("subject"));
         m.setDate(dbSqlTimestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy HH:mm").format(rs.getTimestamp("date")));
         m.setMessageid(rs.getInt("msg_id"));
         memolist.add(m);
      }

        return memolist;
    }
    catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }        
    finally
    {
        DBUtil.closeResultSet(rs);
        DBUtil.closePreparedStatement(ps);
        pool.freeConnection(connection);
    }
}
```

My MemoShowAll looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
          HttpServletResponse response)
          throws ServletException, IOException 
{   

    HttpSession session = request.getSession(); 

    ArrayList<Memo> memolist = DBQueries.selectAllMemoList();

    request.setAttribute("listmemo", memolist);

    String url = "/restricted/MemoList.jsp";

    // forward the request and response to the view
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url);
    dispatcher.forward(request, response); 

}
```

MemoList.jsp

```
<z:rows>
    <core:forEach var="each" items="${listmemo}">
    <z:row>
        <img src="${each.userpicture}" border=0 >
        <z:label value="${each.username}"/>
        <z:label value="${each.subject}"/>
        <z:label value="${each.date}"/>
    </z:row>
    </core:forEach>
</z:rows>
```

Cheers,
BB

Comment: what is stored in field userpicture ? image path ? and where the image is stored ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that i bypass this issue is by using a servlet to expose the image to the client. For this to work, you should store the image bytes retrieved from the database to the user's `session` object.

In the html i have `< img src="/imageRender?id=someimageid"/ >`

Therefore when the browser will try to render the image, it will make a call to  `/imageRender` where my servlet listens to. And the servlet will read the input parameter and then render the image from the session object based on the parameter.

Some helpful links are:

1) [Display servlet as img src using session attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410002/display-servlet-as-img-src-using-session-attribute)

2) [Writing image to servlet response with best performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979758/writing-image-to-servlet-response-with-best-performance)

Pay special attention to link 2 @BalusC answer to the place where it says `In the ImageDAO#find() you can use ResultSet#getBinaryStream() to get the image as an InputStream from the database.`

In your case you can create a List of DAO objects that will represent each row from db.